# Is there a mapply equivalent in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Using `dplyr`: is there a way to loop over variables in a data frame and pass both the data and the variable name to a custom function?

I have a solution for this using `mapply` in base R. In the interest of learning I am wondering if there is a neat `dplyr`-way to achieve the same result.

Here is a small example, where each column in a data frame is transformed by adding a constant. The constant I wish to add is different for each variable, as listed in `myconstants`.

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata <- tibble(
  a = 1:5,
  b = 1:5,
  c = 1:5
)
myconstants <- tibble(
  a = 10,
  b = 20
)
custom_function <- function (x, y, k) {
  constant <- if (is.null(k[[y]])) 0 else k[[y]]
  x + constant
}

# solution in base R
foo <- mapply(
  custom_function, 
  mydata, 
  names(mydata), 
  MoreArgs = list(k = myconstants)
  ) %>%  
  as_tibble()
```

Comment: See `pmap` in the `purrr` package. The `purrr` function `map` is analogous to `lapply`. `map2` and `pmap` are analogous to `mapply`.

Comment: Thanks @eipi10! Exactly what I was looking for: 

`map2_df(.x = mydata, .y = names(mydata), custom_function, k = myconstants)`